# Why is this basic if statement looping?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, if-statement, nested-loops

I have an if/else to call the template for a post type, and for some reason I cannot seem to figure out why the first portion is stuck in an infinite loop.

Here's the main page loop:

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php if ( has_term('bands', 'work_family')):

        get_template_part('content', 'single-bands');


    else:

        get_template_part('content', 'single-work');

    endif;  ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the `single-bands` template that is getting loaded, because if I comment out that line and stick some text in there it works just as it should. Here's that template:

```
<header class="fl-post-header">
    <h1 class="fl-post-title" itemprop="headline">
        <?php
        // strip "Songs by" from titles for archive page
            $title = get_the_title();
            $prefix = 'Songs by ';
            $stripper = $title;

            if (substr($stripper, 0, strlen($prefix)) == $prefix) {
                    $stripper = substr($stripper, strlen($prefix));
            }
            ?>
            <?php echo $stripper; ?>
            <?php edit_post_link( _x( 'Edit', 'Edit post link text.', 'fl-automator' ) ); ?>
            TEMPLATE LOADED CORRECTLY IF YOU SEE THIS
        </h1>
    </header><!-- .fl-post-header -->
    <div class="fl-content <?php FLTheme::content_class(); ?>">
        <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <article <?php post_class( 'work-post' ); ?> id="fl-post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" itemscope="itemscope">

            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part('content', 'band-performances') ?>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>
```

Nothing else loop related on the page and all the html works fine when I load the template directly instead of in that outer loop from the other page. I'm relatively certain the problem is in the header, because the rest of the template does not get looped, just that.

Comment: It's because your template part `single-bands` _also loops through posts_ with the `if ( have_posts() ) {....` and `while(have_posts()) {...
`.  Remove that if / while condition, and simply use the part within the loop that renders the post.

Comment: That did it, thank you!!